# Generate Java bindings for TinyB

Tags: java, cmake

I need to use the TinyB library which is a C library. As a Java programmer, I'm just used to Jar files. When I build TinyB with CMake, no Jar files are generated. How can I create Jar files for TinyB?

Comment: jar files are _Java_ Archive files. Compiling a C or C++ program won't create a jar as they're two completely different languages. To use C or C++ libraries, you'll need to use the JNI.

Comment: Actually he just has to set a build option. TinyB provides Java bindings in a JAR if you ask their build to do so. ;-)

Comment: @ColinShewell Do you mind commenting why the answers were not helpful  (and how you did it instead) or otherwise accepting one? The other question indicates, you figured out how to tell CMake to build the Java Bindings. http://stackoverflow.com/q/41483380/2799037

Comment: @usr1234567 that question was asked within the last few minutes, I have not yet had time as I am busy trying to solve the problem that I have in that question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That library is not a Java library, but a native library written in C. You cannot directly use it in Java directly as you are used to so that it works platform independently wherever Java runs.

You can use the library, but you bind yourself to the operating system for which the native library is built. If this is no problem for you as you just write your program for your RaspberryPi, you can use JNI or JNA to use that native library.

If this is actually about http://iotdk.intel.com/docs/master/tinyb/, you should maybe read the instructions fully and not blindly execute commands without knowing what you are doing. Those people already provide Java bindings that probably use JNI or JNA to talk to the native library, but you have to enable the generation of the Java bindings (the JAR) by a build switch.